# Breaking my code down into a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a battleship game to practice my programming skills. I have functional code but was wondering if anyone can help me break my code down into a for loop?

```
import random
def main():
    board = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        board.append(random.randint(1,50))

    print(board) #test purposes 

    guess=int(input("enter number between 1-50"))

    if guess == board[0]: 
       print("hit")
       board[0]="hit"
    elif guess != board[0]:
       print("miss")
       board[0]="miss"
```

Note i want to carry out the if statement multiple times to check for board[0-5].
Instead of repeating it 5 times I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
for x in range(0,5):
    if guess == board[x]:
        print("hit")
        board[x]="hit"
    else:
        print("miss")
        board[x]="miss"
```

But this is not working as it takes just 1 input whereas I want it to take 5. For each input it has to check if input is equal to board[0-5]

Thank You in advance for any help.

Comment: You have to ask the new guess every time (i.e. move `guess=...` inside the loop)

Comment: Don't you want your 'guess=int(input("enter number between 1-50"))' to be in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

write guess in a for loop,be careful about indentation

```
import random
def main():
    board = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        board.append(random.randint(1, 50))
        guess = int(input("enter number between 1-50 : "))
        print(board)  # test purposes

        if guess == board[0]:
            print("hit")
            board[0] = "hit"
        elif guess != board[0]:
            print("miss")
            board[0] = "miss"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but I believe it to be this:

```
import random 
def main():
    board = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        board.append(random.randint(1,50))

    print(board) #test purposes

    guesses = []
    try_nr = 0
    while try_nr < 5:
        try_nr += 1  
        guess = int(input("enter number between 1-50"))
        guesses.append(guess)

    for i in enumerate(guesses):
        i = i[0]
        if guesses[i] in board: 
            print("hit")
            # board[0]="hit" --> not quite sure what you want to achieve here?
        else:
            print("miss")
            # board[0]="miss" --> not quite sure what you want to achieve here?
```

**NB1**: There are other more neat/dense ways to code this, but this helps you to get going. See if you can perfect it for yourself if needed.

**NB2**: I have changed your `elif` statement into `else`. Your equation can only have two possible answers (either a hit or a miss). By using `elif` you are forcing python to reconsider/re-calculate your if-statement fully while using `else` it only considers the if-statement once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the enumerate() function to add a counter to your for loop. This will be useful.

```
board = [12, 4, 76, 2]
for index, number in enumerate(board):
    print index, number

#output
# 0 12
# 1 4
# 2 76
# 3 2
```

You said you want to take 5 guesses? You could do something like this:

```
for i in range(5):

    guess=int(input("enter number between 1-50"))

    for index, number in enumerate(board):
        if guess == number
            print("hit")
            board[index] = "hit"
        else:
            print("miss")
            board[index] = "miss"
```